# OpenCV for python error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Fixed: The method I use for grabbing the images is to create a list of all files with extension '.jpeg'.  A rogue file in the directory was corrupted.  Deleted it and all is well.

I'm currently using openCV for python in order to do some relatively simple image processing.  The program I've been using has worked up until this point.  And when I say work I mean that it hasn't thrown any errors like this prior, and I didn't actually change any code.  I ran the program, it ran correctly, I ran it again, and it began throwing errors.  This is the error message I am receiving:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/opencv20150810-54114-etkrvl/opencv-2.4.12/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3739

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgProccv2.py", line 86, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.error: /tmp/opencv20150810-54114-etkrvl/opencv-2.4.12/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

This is sorta disconcerting due to openCV being a bit of a pain to install and mess with on mac.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note.  I've been hopping between pycharm and vim as text editors.  When I open this file in vim it looks completely garbled and incoherent.  Not sure if this is an issue with pycharm or what.

Thanks for the help and apologies on the formatting.  I know it looks kinda ugly.

Comment: How do you get the images you are trying to process? This error generally means that your image frame is empty. It would probably help, if you edit your post to include parts of the program that load the image and then convert it to grayscale

Comment: I really need to spend some time and get better at searching for answers.  Found the issue with a little help a previous answer.  The issue was that there was a rogue .jpeg file in the directory that got corrupted or something.  Normally what I do is create a list of all .jpeg extension files in the directory.  Removed it and everything worked fine.  Thanks though.

Comment: No problem, have fun coding